# Como atualizar a quantidade de mensagens com socket.io em um app Angular Ionic3 para determinado endpoint?

Tags: angular, ionic3, socket.io

Quero implementar um ícone em uma view que traga a quantidade de mensagens que um usuário tem em sua caixa, porém a atualização da informação da quantidade deve ocorrer em tempo real conforme o modelo abaixo do Facebook:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu tenho um endpoint de uma API que traz a lista de mensagens:

```
http://localhost:8080/clientes/mensagens/
```

Para buscar esta lista de mensagens eu criei um service que roda perfeitamente:

```
buscarMensagens() : Observable<Mensagem[]>  {
        return this.http.get<Mensagem[]>(`${CONF_API.baseUrl}/clientes/mensagem/`);
    }
```

Dentro do controlador da view criei uma variável que recebe a quantidade de mensagens:

```
quantificarMensagens(){
this.mensagemService.buscarMensagens().subscribe(response => {
  this.qtdMensagem = response.lenght();
})
```

Ele busca perfeitamente a quantidade de mensagens do usuário.

O grande problema aqui é que isso não ocorre de forma dinâmica, ou seja, quando chega mais uma mensagem para o usuário o valor não atualiza em tempo real, pois é necessário um novo request.

Estudando mais profundamente me informaram que para esta situação eu devo utilizar o Socket, porém os exemplos que encontrei se refere a criação de um chat utilizando tal tecnologia, e não consegui compreender em como aplicar isso em minha situação.

Então pergunto: Como utilizar Socket para atualizar em tempo real a quantidade de mensagens que chegam na caixa do usuário utilizando este este endpoint? `http://localhost:8080/clientes/mensagens/`

Comment: Voce esta fazendo um get request e não se conectando ao socket.io

Comment: Sim, é isso que quero fazer mas não sei como.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seguinte, por que eles falam chat?

Pelo motivo de ele ser basicamente requerido socket pois o usuario precisa receber a informação sem o "refresh", outra maneira você por um timer para isso, mais pesando de outra maneira, e um consumo de recursos tremenda manter um timer, imagina isso para um celular? a bateria chorraria... agora por que o socket? ele faz a conexão com o servidor e mantem ela ativa a escutando o tempo todo...

pq um chat e a forma mais simples para aprender socket pois nele vc pode criar salas uma para cada pagina para admin/cliente ou apenas admin e cliente e separar as paginas por paginaInicial;0;0 e interpretar essa informação do lado cliente....

segue ai pra você um socket basico em node com uso de cookies para cada vez que o cliente abrir uma pagina ele reaproveitar a conexão...

desculpe pelo português tenho preguiça de usar introdução, metodologia, conclusão

[Socket básico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/72589/problema-com-session-e-nodejs)

ah lendo melhor seu post você terá que reescrever esse backend seu em node ou fazer um método de enviar essa info para o node e ele a retornar trabalhada ou que ele apenas a dispare para todos do canal desejado

é isso, caso esteja errado alguém pode da uma força ai